# Akka 2.1 Remote: sharing actor across systems

Tags: akka, actor, remote-actors

I'm learnin about remote actors in Akka 2.1 and I tried to adapt the [counter example provided by Typesafe](https://github.com/typesafehub/akka-scala-sbt.g8/tree/akka-2.1-scala-2.10). 
I implemented a quick'n'dirty UI from the console to send ticks. And to quit with asking(and showing the result) the current count.

The idea is to start a master node that will run the Counter actor and some client node that will send messages to it through remoting. However I'd like to achieve this through configuration and minimal changes to code. So by changing the configuration local actors could be used.

I found [this blog entry](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2012/11/remote-actors-discovering-akka.html) about similar problem where it was necessary that all API calls go through one actor even though there are many instances running.

I wrote similar configuration but I cant get it to work. My current code does use remoting but it creates a new actor on the master for each new node and I can't get it to connect to existing actor without explicitly giving it the path(and defying the point of configuration). However this is not what I want since state cannot be shared between JVMs this way.

Full runnable code available [through a git repo](https://bitbucket.org/edofic/counter-remote)

This is my config file

```
akka {
    actor {
        provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
        deployment {
            /counter {
                remote = "akka://ticker@127.0.0.1:2552"
            }
        }
    }
    remote {
        transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
        log-sent-messages = on
        netty {
            hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        }
    }
}
```

And full source

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.util._

case object Tick
case object Get

class Counter extends Actor {
  var count = 0

  val id = math.random.toString.substring(2)
  println(s"\nmy name is $id\ni'm at ${self.path}\n")
  def log(s: String) = println(s"$id: $s")

  def receive = {
    case Tick =>
      count += 1
      log(s"got a tick, now at $count")
    case Get  =>
      sender ! count
      log(s"asked for count, replied with $count")
  }
}

object AkkaProjectInScala extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("ticker")
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val counter = system.actorOf(Props[Counter], "counter")

  def step {
    print("tick or quit? ")
    readLine() match {
      case "tick" => counter ! Tick
      case "quit" => return
      case _ =>
    }
    step
  }
  step

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)

  val f = counter ? Get
  f onComplete {
    case Failure(e) => throw e
    case Success(count) => println("Count is " + count)
  }

  system.shutdown()
}
```

I used `sbt run` and in another window `sbt run -Dakka.remote.netty.port=0` to run it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out I can use some sort of pattern. Akka remote allows only for deploying on remote systems(can't find a way to make it look up on remote just through configuration..am I mistaken here?).

So I can deploy a "scout" that will pass back the ActorRef. Runnable code available on the original repo under branch "scout-hack". Because this feels like a hack. I will still appreciate configuration based solution.

The actor

```
case object Fetch

class Scout extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case Fetch => sender ! AkkaProjectInScala._counter
  }
}
```

Counter actor creating is now lazy

```
lazy val _counter = system.actorOf(Props[Counter], "counter")
```

So it only executes on the master(determined by the port) and can be fetched like this

```
val counter: ActorRef = {
  val scout = system.actorOf(Props[Scout], "scout")
  val ref = Await.result(scout ? Fetch, timeout.duration) match {
    case r: ActorRef => r
  }
  scout ! PoisonPill
  ref
}
```

And full config

```
akka {
    actor {
        provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
        deployment {
            /scout {
                remote = "akka://ticker@127.0.0.1:2552"
            }
        }
    }
    remote {
        transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
        log-sent-messages = on
        netty {
            hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I also found a clean-ish way: check configuration for "counterPath" anf if present  actorFor(path) else create actor. Nice and you can inject the master when running and code is much cleaner than with the "scout" but it still has to decide weather to look up or create an actor. I guess this cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your git project and it actually works fine, aside from a compilation error, and that you must start the sbt session with `-Dakka.remote.netty.port=0` parameter to the jvm, not as parameter to `run`.

You should also understand that you don't have to start the Counter actor in both processes. In this example it's intended to be created from the client and deployed on the server (port 2552). You don't have to start it on the server. It should be enough to create the actor system on the server for this example.

Comment: Fixed the code. Changing parameters does not change the behavior. It works but not in the way I want it too. To rephrase my question: how(if possible) can I configure akka not to create new actors for every client but to share the existing one?